# Is $e^{2\pi i m/k}$ a $k$th root of unity even if $\gcd (m,k)>1$?

Tags: complex-numbers, analytic-number-theory

At the beginning of Ch.8 of the book Apostol's Analytic Number Theory, it is written:

> [consider] ... the exponential function $$f(n) = e^{2\pi i mn/k} $$ 
>   where $m$ and $k$ are fixed integers. The number $e^{2\pi i m/k}$ is a $k$th root of unity and $f(n)$ is its $n$th power.

Is this true if $\gcd (m,k)>1$? Isn't it necessary for $m$ to be either prime or $1$?

For example let $k=2m$ and $m$ is a prime, then the number $e^{2\pi i m/k}$ will be $\frac{k}2$th of root of unity. Later on the book it appears that the $\gcd (m,k)=1$ is never considered.

Comment: There is no *one* $k$-th root of unity, but $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that is necessary (and sufficient) for $z$ to be a $k$th root of unity is for $z^k = 1$. That is all.

$$(e^{2 \pi i m / k})^k = e^{2 \pi i m} = 1$$

So they're all $k$th roots.

If, for example, $k = a \cdot m$, then it will also be true that it's an $a$th root:

$$(e^{2 \pi i m / k})^a = (e^{2 \pi i m/(a\cdot m)})^a = 1$$

So given $k = q \cdot m$, then for which $b \in \mathbb N$ is this a $b$th root?
$$(e^{2 \pi i m / k})^b = (e^{2 \pi i /q})^b = 1 \quad\text{ iff }\quad b/q \in \mathbb Z \; .$$
Now $b/q = b/(k/m) = bm/k$.
This tells us that $e^{2 \pi i m /k}$ is a $b$th root precisely when $b$ is a multiple of $k/m$. So what is the smallest integral multiple of $k/m$? It is $k/\mathrm{gcd}(k,m)$. To see this, first imagine simplifying the fraction by eliminating common factors: this is $\mathrm{gcd}(k,m)$. Then we multiply by the denominator, which is now $m/\mathrm{gcd}(k,m)$. We multiply this by $k/m$ to obtain its smallest integral multiple.

In conclusion, $e^{2 \pi i m / k}$ is a $b$th root for precisely the following $b$:

$$b \in \{ n \cdot k / \mathrm{gcd}(k,m) : n \in \mathbb N\}$$

Answer (score 1):

2 is the square root of 4, it is also the fourth root of 16. 1 is the cube root of 1, it is also the twelfth root of 1. All that matter is that if you multiply the number by itself $k$ times, you get the number it's meant to be the $k$th root of.

Answer (score 0):

In the situation  you're worried about, where the gcd of $k$ and $m$ is some $d>1$, you'd have $m=dm'$ and $k=dk'$ for some $m'$ and $k'$ whose gcd is 1.  Since $m/k=m'/k'$, your $e^{2\pi inm/k}$ equals $e^{2\pi inm'/k'}$, where your worries have vanished because the gcd of $m'$ and $k'$ is $1$.

Comment: I have two problems to understand: $e^{2\pi inm'/k'}$ are the k'-th roots of unity and k'<k. and, how  to prove that $e^{2πinm/k}$ are distinct numbers for n=1,…,k  even if m is an arbitrary positive integer.

Comment: With the notation in my answer, the numbers $e^{2\pi inm'/k'}$ are $k'$-th roots of unity because their $k'$-th powers are $e^{2\pi inm'}=1$ because $nm'$ is an integer.  As $n$ varies from $1$ to $k$, these numbers, which are the same as $e^{2\pi inm/k}$, are not all distinct; there are only $k'$ distinct ones among them, because there are only $k'$ distinct $k'$-th roots of unity.  Specifically, the values of $e^{2\pi inm/k}$ are distinct while $n$ ranges from $1$ to $k'$, and they repeat periodically ($d$ times) thereafter.

Comment: @Edi - You should not move the goalposts on a question like this. Your question is an official record of what you are asking, not your comments. If you meant to ask something but did not clarify sufficiently, then you should edit your original question. If you have additional, unrelated questions, then you should open new ones.

Comment: @Myridium, what I asked in the comment were what I meant by question in the OP. My bad that I didn't asked them clearly.

Answer (score 0):

The $k$-th roots of unity are k, as already explained in other answer.
Those which are not also the roots of a lower $j < k$, i.e. when $\gcd(m,k)=1$ with your symbology, are called **Primitive k-th Roots** of 1.